# Error getting correct text after pushing, and then getting the front() from the std::queue

Tags: c++, stl, queue, fstream

I am in a bit of a trouble here... I will start with the requirements first:

1. Try to send data (msg) to the server
2. If it fails, store it in a local hard disk file, as a list of CSV entries
3. Try to send the msg data to the server at some predetermined point.
4. If a msg is sent successfully, remove it from the file
5. Continue the process till sending data to server fails. and go to step 2

What I have done:

1. Used fstream object to write the failed msgs to a local file
2. Used fstream object to read from this file, and store in a dynamically created std::queue
3. For each msg read from the file, push it in the queue
4. After pushing all msgs, take the first msg using std::front(), and read it into the custom object data structure.

The problem is:
*I print the msgs read from the hard disk file before and after pushing it into the queue. Before pushing the queue, the data I print into a messageBox/text file logs is absolutely fine. But when I print the same data after getting the queue:front() it prints all junk.**

I am not an expert on queues and STLs, so I need a guiding hand.

The code is as follows:

```
 
    class CDFCQueueMsgs
    {
    public:
        char chDFCMsg_1;
        char chDFCMsg_2;
        char chDFCMsg_3;
        char chDFCMsg_4;
        char chDFCMsg_5;
    };
// This is how I created the fstream obj to read the file
    fstream_IOData_Read.open(pChPersistingFileLocation, ios::in);
```

// The CSVs that I write to and read back from the file are like:
// 1111222233334444,1234,05,0011123456,20100102112233,1234567890,7,N

// Given below is how I write to the file:
void CDataQueueingAndPersisting::WriteQueueMsgsToFile(char *pchAppendMsgToPersistentFile)
{
    char chWriteBuffer[512] = {0};
    fstream_IOData_Write.flush();
    sprintf(chWriteBuffer, "%s\r\n", pchAppendMsgToPersistentFile);
    if(NULL != pchAppendMsgToPersistentFile) fstream_IOData_Write.write(chWriteBuffer,strlen(chWriteBuffer));
}

// Given below is how I read from the file:
    while(fstream_IOData_Read >> chSingleDFCMsg)
    {
        bDataRead = ReplicateQueueInProcessMemory( (BYTE*) chSingleDFCMsg);
        RtlZeroMemory(chSingleDFCMsg, sizeof(chSingleDFCMsg));
    }

// ReplicateQueueInProcessMemory is like:
    pChDelimitedStrPtr = strtok((char *)byteSingleRawQueueMsg, ",");

// to read every comma delimited field in the single line as shown above. I use multiple strtok()s to read all the fields of the string.

// After this I get the front message in the queue:
        CDFCQueueMsgs oDfcQueueMsg_TopMsg;
        CDFCQueueMsgs & refDfcQueueMsg_TopMsg = oDfcQueueMsg_TopMsg;
        refDfcQueueMsg_TopMsg = *oCDataQueueingAndPersisting.poDFCMsgQUEUE.front();

// Now I get the respective member fields to the object type the queue holds:
        strncpy(g_chBuffer, refDfcQueueMsg_TopMsg.chDFCMsg_1, sizeof(refDfcQueueMsg_TopMsg.chDFCMsg_1));

// Now I Log the "g_chBuffer" variable in my log files. I also log each field in my logs:
/*
Before Pushing into queue, I log the string from the read buffer, the fields get logged fine like this:
09:50:45:093 EVENT: chDFCMsg_1:1111222233334444
chDFCMsg_2:1234
chDFCMsg_3:05
chDFCMsg_4:0011123456
chDFCMsg_5:20100102112233

After pushing and gettting the Queue::front() I see the same fields like this:
10:45:54:495 EVENT: 2`ÃÛ¬S
10:45:54:495 EVENT: ¬S
10:45:54:495 EVENT:`á
10:45:54:495 EVENT: 
10:45:54:495 EVENT: 
*/

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: There is not enough source code to understand your problem. We need: What is CDFCQueueMsgs content, how do you create and push an entry in the queue, and how you retrieve and print it from the queue.

Comment: I edited the post to add how "CDFCQueueMsgs" is declared. If CDFCQueueMsgs oCDFCQueueMsgs is an object, Queue::push(oCDFCQueueMsgs ); is how I push it. I use my Queue object's queue:front() to take the first msg.

Comment: -1 There is no STL queue in your code, yet your question is about that.

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach - The question has to clear in either of the two fronts: 1.The theory has to clear (or) 2. The code has to be there. I think I made my question in theory. If both, great, if not Try to understand. Thx.

Comment: sounds pretty much like the STL queue is not the problem. Try to remove (for testing) all operations working on pointers that might overwrie the memory. Also double check if you double delete a pointer.

Comment: @Philipp - Thanks for your comment. I am not deleting any pointers at all, and I have checked if it is overwriting, I will check again though. WHat I am doing is a simple operation, push the object with strings in the queue; then retrieve it using front and print the string. Boom! It gives me weird characters everytime I print after pushing into the queue and using front() to get the first object in the queue. I thought it is all about data conversion, but am not sure as I have not handled queues before.

Comment: maybe you are pushing a pointer to a stack variable which is released till the point where you do the pop()?

Comment: @Philip:I have not pop-ed the queue msg yet. I will do it after the front() message is read correctly. I changed the pointer to a reference like this: *** CDFCQueueMsgs & refDfcQueueMsg_TopMsg = oDfcQueueMsg_TopMsg; *** Still the same junk. I guess the junk loves me!! ;-)

Comment: so I agree with the others that you will have to show more code.

Comment: @Philipp: The point is not about to agree or disagree with others, rather it is about helping someone like me who is asking for help. I appreciate the fact that lot of good people like you, have taken time off to answer - I am honoured. But writing that you agree with others or Do not does not make a difference or help - Thanks.

Comment: Daniel. You do not put enough source code in your post. We can not help you if you do not give us enough information. (cf my first comment).

Comment: What do the entries in the CSV file look like?  Millions of people use the STL queue successfully to store stuff every day.  Your problem is because of the code you aren't posting, not some general issue with a queue as you've described your use of it.  This whole 'theory' concept of yours is flat-out ridiculous.  You have a problem in practice, not in theory.  And you haven't posted enough code to know what the problem is.

Comment: Guys, I have updated my question with more clarity and code, plz go through and point my mistake plz. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

what is the content of oCDataQueueingAndPersisting? (Especially the type of poDFCMsgQUEUE)

If I am right:
* I think it is actually a queue of pointer and not a queue of data.
* which mean that the memory pointed by poDFCMsgQUEUE.front() is not the good one.

for example you can not do that:

```
void function1()
{
  myItem i;
  myQueueOfPointer.push(&myItem)
}

void main()
{
  function1()
  cout << myQueueOfPointer.front() // error
}
```

In this case, myItem is destroy after function1 return. So the address in myQueueOfPointer::front() is still pointing at nothing (a memory that can be use by other function etc...). This is why you print a piece of junk in your second print. The first one succeded because the memory was not yet overwrite by another part of your program.

PS:

As we all did request, you did not post the part where you push element in the queue. I will tell you one last time but if you do not post it, we can not help you (even the opposite, your post get downvoted).

An advice for the future (if you want to use this site efficiently):

- Present well you problem (this was ok)
- Paste the source code of your problem

  - Well indented, ans structured (Like i did in this post)
  - If it is complex: reduce the source code as much as possible (with only interesting part)

Hope it will help you

Comment: Hi Phong, thanks for your reply. I will check the points you had mentioned and see if I can resolve this issue. Thanks again. Also, I do acknowledge that my post is scrappy and unclear to say the least. I will come up with better posts in future.

Comment: You were spot on, I created a queue of pointers and not the actual objects, so I got junk as I was pointing to nothing but junk :-) Thanks you very much for your help, I owe you, the reason why my code works now. Thanks. Cheers!

Comment: dont forget to accept answer, If you do not, people will avoid answering your question.

Comment: Phong, Sorry but this is the first time I am using this website, I could not find the accept answer option anywhere, did u mean the UP and DOWN arrows next to the answer?

Comment: I advise you to read the faq of this site for learning how to use this site. If you like the answer of any post which correctly answer your question, you can upvote it with UP arrow (and opposite). To accept an answer for your question, you click on the "v" below the DOWN arrow.

Answer (score 0):

std::queue::front retrieve the Value of the first entry or its Reference.

So your code:

```
CDFCQueueMsgs oDfcQueueMsg_TopMsg;
CDFCQueueMsgs * poDfcQueueMsg_TopMsg = & oDfcQueueMsg_TopMsg;
poDfcQueueMsg_TopMsg = oCDataQueueingAndPersisting.poDFCMsgQUEUE.front();
```

should be:

```
// take the reference of the queue::front in oDfcQueueMsg_TopMsg 
CDFCQueueMsgs& oDfcQueueMsg_TopMsg;
oDfcQueueMsg_TopMsg = oCDataQueueingAndPersisting.poDFCMsgQUEUE.front();
```

or

```
// copy the queue::front() into oDfcQueueMsg_TopMsg
CDFCQueueMsgs oDfcQueueMsg_TopMsg;
oDfcQueueMsg_TopMsg = oCDataQueueingAndPersisting.poDFCMsgQUEUE.front();
```

Comment: Hi Phong, Well I tried the (1st) reference approach and the result is the same, I get junk. The second approach gives me a build error: *** Error 2 error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'CDataQueueingAndPersisting::CDFCQueueMsgs *' (or there is no acceptable conversion) CDataQueueingAndPersisting.cpp 170 ***